# Deploy Function App .csproj from Github

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

I have a function app project in multi project visual studio solution. I have an ARM template set up with GitHub as the source:

```
"properties": {
"RepoUrl": "[parameters('funcapp_reponame')]",
"branch": "[parameters('funcapp_branch')]",
"IsManualIntegration": true,
```

}

I have also added the following to deploy from the function app project:

```
"siteConfig": {
"appSettings": [
{
    "name": "Project",
    "value": "ProjectName"
}]
```

},

The template successfully creates the Function app resource, but not the functions. Looking at the deployment error log in the Azure portal I get:

```
'D:\home\site\repository\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj' is not a deployable project
```

Looking at the files copied to Azure via FTP I can see that the full solution has been copied over and the deployment process looks to be selecting the correct folder. Is the presence of the .csproj causing the issue? The various example ARM templates for deploying functions on github don't appear to use visual studio projects.

Comment: It works with my test function app https://github.com/davidebbo-test/FunctionAppVS2017. Could you [share a repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue) that demonstrates the issue? Also, can you share your function app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for the response. I deleted the resource group yesterday and tried running the ARM template again so you could see the app. This time it worked fine! Unfortunately as I deleted the resource group I guess we have deleted the log of the previous deployment failure.

Comment: Odd. If you see this again, let me know and we'll take a look.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I tried a deployment to a new subscription and had this issue again. As suggested in the contact your team indirectly I created a temp function app in the same resource group and copied the log: 2018-01-03T14:39:00.189 Function started (Id=f1677d90-4861-4cf3-9c17-5747d2efb92e). The other function app in the resource group is the one with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your Function App's csproj, you have:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="1.0.0-beta1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.0-alpha6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So it's referencing a very old `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package. In your project, go to Manage NuGet Packages, and update to the latest, which right now is 1.0.7. Also, make sure to install any relevant VS updates under Tools / Extension and Updates.

Comment: Upadated VS and the NuGet packages. Synced back to the correct Github branch. Resynced Function in azure portal Deployment Options. Received the same error. (Also checked csproj had 1.0.7 via FTP - so files had updated). Deleted the resource group. Ran full deployment and it worked first time. So same pattern as last time. Apologies if I'm doing something dimwitted!

Comment: @Paul any chance you can [share a simple repository](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue) that repros the problem? Does the same happen if you create a new test app, enable local git and just push your repo? If we can repro on our end, it'll be easier to investigate. Thanks!